# Redshift View Definition Restriction

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to restrict users from seeing view definition (sql)?

Code to hide view definition in redshift.

I would appreciate if you could share how to do it with the code.

Code to hide view definition in redshift. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I think you can revoke `SELECT` privilege on the underlying tables from the users. So, users will be able to query the view but won't be able to see the underlying SQL definition. `REVOKE SELECT ON table_name FROM user_name;`

Comment: Revoking SELECT from the underlying table doesn't do anything about the view. Permission to view data in a table is not the same as permission to view the definition or metadata. Redshift fine grained access control lets you manage them separately. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_metadata_security.html